# Exporting results from Select By Location comparisons of each line in one shapefile with polygons in another?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, select-by-location

I use ArcMap 10 and I am trying to export multiple selections (a.k.a 'Select by Location') from one file against another.

I start by selecting the first line of shapefile A and I want to select all the polygons of shapefile B that are inside of shapefile A (B polygons contained in A), to then export them as shapefile_1.

And this process to be repeated for x records in A to produce more shapefiles (shapefile_1, shapefile_2, ... shapefile_x).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

As from the comment, you could loop on each feature then run the selection by location on a feature layer. There are different types of loops for this purpose 1) based on a selection by attribute for each FID in a feature layer or 2) directly based on the geometry in a cursor. Here is the code with a cursor, which is more straightforward IMHO. You get the geometry of each feature as the property of each row using row.getValue(shapefieldname). Note that for later versions of ArcGIS, arcpy.da cursors are better.

```
import arcpy

fcA = "fcA.shp"
fcB = "fcB.shp"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcB, "layerfcB") #selection is performed on a layer

desc = arcpy.Describe(fcA)
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName # get the name of the field containing geometry information

i=0
with arcpy.SearchCursor(fcA) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: #loop on each feature from fcA
        i=i+1
        arcpy.SelectByLocation_management("layerfcB", "within", row.getValue(shapefieldname)) #select based on geometry
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("layerfcB", "output_path" +str(i)+".shp") # export the selected features in a new feature class
```

Comment: +1 Excellent solution but I think it would be worth mentioning in your answer, prior to presenting the code, that the "trick" you are using is to use a geometry, which you reference as `row.getValue(shapefieldname)`, in place of a layer name.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Radouxju. However, I would like to save the selected rows in B in relation to each A row in separate shapefiles.

Also, I am getting syntax error (parsing error) on the last line.

Thank you for your help so far

Comment: this is what my code should do, but I forgot to implement "i" in the loop (corrected now).

Comment: I still get a syntax error on the very last line. I understand that it is trying to write the output to be "fsB(i).shp" format but for some reason I cannot run the code. Thank you for help so far

Comment: fcB is the name of the string variable with the full path , I've replace it with a simple string.